# Transfer learning (on pre-trained inception net model) for multi label classification is giving similar probability for all labels

Tags: deep-learning, multilabel-classification, inception, transfer-learning

Number of labels: 1000, Dataset size: 200000 images
Final probability for 1000 labels is in the range of 0.3 to 0.34.
I was expecting large variation in probabilities. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong. I am following [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-label-image-classification-with-inception-net-cbb2ee538e30) tutorial

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by score here?

Comment: By score I mean probability

Comment: Probability of what? The highest probability for the corresponding class? The probability for one specific class?

Comment: Probability of each class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, the example code for a low number of classes (<200) works well. When moving to more classes the imbalance data makes the network converge to the same numbers. You have imbalance data because now each output is a binary classifier by its own, this doesn't happen with softmax. The way to mitigate the problem is to use `weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits` and set `pos_weight` to a positive number > 1 (10 works). But I still don't get very good results.